# start windows phone application analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013, analysis

I finished a windows phone project. And try to do Debug->Start windows phone application analysis on visual studio 2012 (also 2013), but it doesn't work, and a dialog box pops up:

[image: error]

now I want to start windows phone application analysis on my project. how can I do this??

PS: I tried create new app from the windows phone template, it has the same error!

Comment: Have the same issue in VS 2013. And then starting analysis from Project(RightClick) -> Open Store Test Kit -> Automated Tests -> Start WPAA  - visual studio just stops working and relaunching.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and alternatively i had error when opening .sap files too with :

> Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.DeviceNotFoundException

This last error [point me](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/f8c13d28-ef0e-48d1-bf67-4fcbd8da35bf/applcation-deployment-tool-microsoftsmartdeviceconnectivitydevicenotfoundexception?forum=wptools) that you have to install [SDK Update for Windows Phone 7.8](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) and everything work now.
Surprising that this prerequisite is not specified.